# Fixing Eclipse workspace and project links after moving files

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I had an Eclipse workspace referencing a project located in a folder outside workspace's dir, so the latter only contains `.metadata` directory.

After I changed computer I changed my username, so workspace couldn't find project anymore. To make stuff work I created hardlink so that Eclipse can still find the project, but I'd like to fix this.

How do I relocate (not move) the project of my workspace so that it finds my project without hard link?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have too many projects, you could remove the existing from your workspace, and use the Import Project feature. Select this menu: `File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into Workspace`

Comment: but will it remember my launch configurations?

Comment: I don't think so, it's related to the workspace. You can export manually from the "Run Configurations" -> "Common" tab -> "Save as" "shared file"